# PhraseA-て + phraseB + ために + phrase C

Tags: て-form, parsing, transitivity

From [here](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10011579861000/k10011579861000.html):

> この行事は、**お盆が終わって**先祖の霊を送るために行われていて、３００年以上の歴史があると言われています。
>   This is event is performed to dispatch the souls of the ancestors ??? and is said to have over 300 years of history.

I'm struggling to parse this sentence. In particular how should I fit お盆が終わって into it?

I cannot make a parsing which contains "Obon ends and...".

The only parsing I can make which makes sense is to have お盆が終わって adverbially modify 行う i.e "the event is performed by means of Obon ending.", but I'm not finding that at all convincing.

Or maybe it could adverbially modify 送る to give "This event is performed to dispatch the souls of the ancestors by Obon ending", i.e. Obon ending is the thing that brings about the dispatch of the souls. I find this only marginally more convincing.

I keep trying to make it say "This is event is performed to end Obon and dispatch the souls of the ancestors", but surely that would require the transitive version: お盆を終えて.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「この行事{ぎょうじ}は、お盆{ぼん}が終{お}わって先祖{せんぞ}の霊{れい}を送{おく}るために行{おこな}われていて、３００年以上{ねんいじょう}の歴史{れきし}があると言{い}われています。」

"Verb Phrase A + Verb Phrase B + ために + Verb Phrase C"

Regarding the first two verb phrases (A & B) ***in this particular sentence***, they are ***not*** exactly in the sequential relationship of "do A first and then do B".  Instead, the two events/actions are taking place ***concurrently***.

The two events/actions are:

1) The obon is coming to an end.

2) People are sending their ancestors' spirits off (to the other world where they are usually found).

Grammatically speaking, 「お盆が終わって」 modifies 「先祖の霊を送る」.  It does not modify 「行われていて」.

Nuance-wise, however, 「お盆が終わって」 is close to 「お盆の終わりに」.

Other examples:

「飲{の}んで食{た}べる」: You do **not** drink first and then eat.  You do both simultaneously.

「歌{うた}って踊{おど}る」: You do **not** first sing and then dance.  You sing while dancing (or dance while singing.)

Answer (score 2):

I think the meaning of this ～て is close to "after ～", so お盆が終わって means "after Obon ends". For example, 宿題して遊びなさい(Play after doing a homework).

So it would be "This event is performed to dispatch the souls of the ancestors after Obon ends and is said to have over 300 years of history."